# Settings window seems to be hidden on Ubuntu 18.04 after changing Ubuntu dock's position

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-dock, gnome-control-center

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After I changed the position of Ubuntu dock from the left side to bottom, I am not able to see the **Settings** window. It seems like the window is opening (because I can see the Settings icon appearing in the dock) but it is hidden from the screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but if you run `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position` in Terminal, then the dock should go back to the left from bottom. Does that make Settings window visible again?

Comment: You could try running gnome-control-center (aka Settings) from Terminal using  `gnome-control-center -v` to see if there's any helpful error messages. Also you might want to check in Display whether a second virtual screen was set up...[see this bug from 17.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1721637)

Comment: @pomsky I tried that but Settings window wasn't visible.

Comment: @Emily Refer to your link I tried to hit Windows button on keyboard, then type `displays`, choose it, then the Displays (and Settings) window is visible.  That's so strange but it resolved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your problem An Tran!

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem i found out that it is because of join display enabled in the display settings
So what i did is changed the dock position to left using

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position LEFT
```

Now the settings window would show up
From there you can go to Devices->Displays and change display mode to single display

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, the default display mode in Devices -> Displays was set to 'Join Displays'. Reverting it back to Single Display did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:
Try this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Then,
search for **settings**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I've been looking a LOT through google ...
Everyone suggesting the "apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center" ... -_-

well as always for my cases I'm looking forward for more complicated issues than they really are.

I found that there were two displays connected in the same time while I just had a simple LVDS screen on my computer.

Check it out with `xrandr -q` to see if you have more than one connected (a VGA for example)

Then discnonnect the one you don't need with `xrandr --output nameofyourunwanteddisplay --off`

Don't know why some apps were showing up only on the second screen and not on the first one. It was a fresh install.

finally worked for me... Hope it could help.